# TypeScript declaration extending class with static method.

Tags: typescript

I am looking for some advice on how to handle this situation correctly.

I have `something.d.ts`

```
export class Sprite {

    static fromFrame(frameId: string): Sprite;
    static fromImage(imageId: string, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number): Sprite;

}

export class TilingSprite extends Sprite {

    static fromFrame(frameId: string, width?: number, height?: number): TilingSprite;
    static fromImage(imageId: string, width?: number, height?: number, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number): TilingSprite;

}
```

In this case, I get the following error:

```
Error   40  Class static side 'typeof TilingSprite' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Sprite'.   Types of property 'fromImage' are incompatible.
    Type '(imageId: string, width?: number, height?: number, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number) => ...' is not assignable to type '(imageId: string, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number)
=> Sprite'.
      Types of parameters 'width' and 'crossorigin' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I cannot really see a way to solve the issue or, it is different behaviour from what I would expect.

How could I cleanly solve this signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I cleanly solve this signature

Not *cleanly* but can be done with function overloading. e.g.:

```
declare class Sprite {
    static fromImage(imageId: string, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number): Sprite;
}

declare class TilingSprite extends Sprite {
    static fromImage(imageId: string, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number): Sprite;
    static fromImage(imageId: string, width?: number, height?: number, crossorigin?: boolean, scaleMode?: number): TilingSprite;
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again @basarat